# How do you output the values along branches of a tree in R?

Tags: r, tree

Given any data frame, how do I get a tree or a list that tells me the value along each of the branches of a tree in R?

For instance, if I have a data frame that looks like:

```
Gender      Under 18?   Student            
M           Y           Y
F           Y           Y
M           N           Y
M           Y           Y
F           N           N
M           N           N
F           N           N
F           Y           N
M           Y           N
```

How do I output the values along the branches like in the tree below?

Tree with values along branches

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally a decision tree is the result of rpart or some other tree based package that creates the decision rules. Which can then be plotted with rpart.plot's `prp` or rattle's `fancyRpartPlot` functions.

But based on your data set I created a function and a set of code (all of which could be put into a big function). Igraph (or diagrammer) can be used to draw decision trees. I have used Igraph. Other packages needed to run this are dplyr and tidyr.

The code is relatively flexible as long as you have the initial table like what you have. So a complete decision path per line.

First step creates a function to count the occurrences of each decision path and add missing decision paths. Next 2 steps create vertex and edge labels which are needed for creating the text in the nodes and on the vertices. The group by statements in this code is needed to make sure that all the values end up in the correct place. The last step is creating a graph and plotting it with the edges and vertices. The picture in this post is the outcome based on your data. If you need different vertex labels as in your example, you could do some ifelse statements, but that doesn't make it flexible. The picture shows the result based on your example data.

The full code is below the picture.

[image]

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(igraph)

# count all the rules at the total grouped level
# add a line for each missing path with a 0
complete_df <- function(dat){

  vars <- names(dat)

  dat %>%
    group_by_all %>%
    summarise(n = n()) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    complete(!!!rlang::syms(vars), fill = list(n = 0)) ##
}

dat <- complete_df(df1)

vertex_labels <- sum(dat$n)
for(i in seq_along(dat[, -ncol(dat)])) {
  out <- dat %>%
    select(1:i, n) %>% 
    group_by_if(is.character) %>% 
    summarise(total = sum(n)) %>% 
    ungroup() %>% 
    pull(total)

  vertex_labels <- c(vertex_labels, out)
}

# labels for inside the nodes    
edge_labels <- NULL
for(i in seq_along(dat[, -ncol(dat)])) {
  out <- dat %>%
    select(1:i) %>% 
    group_by_if(is.character) %>%
    distinct %>% 
    pull(i)

  edge_labels <- c(edge_labels, out)
}

plot(graph.tree(2^(ncol(dat)) - 1, 2), 
     layout=layout_as_tree,
     edge.label = edge_labels,
     vertex.label = vertex_labels
)
```

data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(Gender = c("M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "F", "F", "M"), 
                      Under_18 = c("Y", "Y", "N", "Y", "N", "N", "N", "Y", "Y"), 
                      Student = c("Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N")), 
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Comment: Thank you @phiver this is very helpful :)